# Order of protection dismissal

Tags: restraining-orders

I filed for a request for dismissal of an ofp but my offender was picked up for violating it. They said if I can prove that I filed for a dismissal he will be released but I can no longer look up the case file. Does this mean it was dismissed? If so how do I know for sure? I’ve called everywhere in town including the jail he is being held at and no one can give me any answers except for bouncing me back and fourth from place to place.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean it was dismissed. Anyway, something doesn't add up. Either your request for that protection order was inappropriate (and the granting thereof improper) or granting the dismissal would be improper, especially since the respondent was caught violating it. Move on and find someone else instead of dealing with this because otherwise it will only get worse for either or both of you.

Answer (score 2):

> I filed for a request for dismissal of an ofp but my offender was
>   picked up for violating it. They said if I can prove that I filed for
>   a dismissal he will be released but I can no longer look up the case
>   file. Does this mean it was dismissed? If so how do I know for sure?

The court record of the court that issued the protection order will resolve the question. They would be available, in person, from the clerk of the court that issued it, and it would be easier for them to find if you have a case number. Sometimes a small typo in a person's name, for example, can make records hard to locate.

If you filed a request for dismissal, then there ought to be a record of that. They are saying that even if the judge didn't grant the order of dismissal yet, or the dismissal wasn't yet granted, or, wasn't properly entered in the protection order database, that they will release him (even though the judge does not necessarily have to grant your request for dismissal).